# Bash completions broken

Tags: terminal, bash, homebrew

I am using following bash completions installed via brew:

```
bash-completion
bash-completion@2
```

My .bashrc looks like:

```
if [ -f /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
. /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
fi


if [ -f /usr/local/Cellar/bash-completion/1.3_2/etc/bash_completion ]; then
  BASH_COMPLETION=/usr/local/Cellar/bash-completion/1.3_2/etc/bash_completion
  . /usr/local/Cellar/bash-completion/1.3_2/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

The problem is when I press TAB on an empty prompt on keyboard I get the error:

`-bash: words: bad array subscript`

After removing `/usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` from `.bashrc` error doesn’t happen but I miss out on many completions.

What is the problem here? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is that I should call bash completion from 1.3.2 before `bash-completion@2`. Following is how my `.bashrc` looks, and this solves the problem:

```
if [ -f /usr/local/Cellar/bash-completion/1.3_2/etc/bash_completion ]; then
  BASH_COMPLETION=/usr/local/Cellar/bash-completion/1.3_2/etc/bash_completion
  . /usr/local/Cellar/bash-completion/1.3_2/etc/bash_completion
fi

if [ -f /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
fi
```